# GAE instances sometimes unavailable (502). Console says, “VM restarting”

Tags: cloud, google-app-engine, autoscaling

I have several services which have very little load (several requests per week sometimes). During periods of constant use there appears to be no problems. But after a period of being idle instances appear to be spun down. Web console shows that instance is “being restarted”. In my `app.yaml` I have `automatic_scaling` with `min_num_instances: 1`. However instances continue to be “spun down”. I tried adding `min_idle_instances: 1` as well, however, I got an error (which makes sense):

```
VM-based automatic scaling should NOT have the following parameter(s): [min_idle_instances]
```

Question is how do I prevent the VMs from becoming unavailable/restarting? Am I understanding correctly that scaling down is the cause? Or if it’s not, where can I see some information about the reasons? Instance’s logs look normal to me. Dashboard, Error Reporting, etc. also look rather innocuous. Again, when instance receives requests (or after being re-deployed) it behaves normally without any noticeable problems.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I am having similar problems

Comment: Hello, @Nicholas! No, unfortunately I still haven’t found out what causes the problem.

Comment: Is the entire application becoming and staying unavailable after periods of low load, or are there shorter periods of unavailability, or are you asking about the behavior of the individual VMs?